# How to send event from iOS to javascript in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm doing something Async in an iOS app. It's triggered by javascript. When it's done (somewhere separated in app), I want to let javascript know.
My current solution is a native module inherited from `RCTEventEmitter`, which has the following method:

```
@interface MyEventEmitter : RCTEventEmitter
// ...
end
@implementation
- (void)giveSomethingToJS:(NSString *)something {
  [self sendEventWithName:@"SOME_NAME" body:something];
}
@end
```

Then, when my Async job's done, I call this method:

```
MyEventEmitter *emitter = [[MyEventEmitter alloc] init];
[emitter giveSomethingToJS:@{}];
```

And obviously, `emitter.bridge` is nil and the app crashed because of assert `bridge != nil`. So how am I supposed to get the bridge and let `*emitter`(the instance) know. Or how can I get the right instance with bridge initialized?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that in the React-Native iOS SDK, `RCTEventEmitter` subclasses should not be initialized by you. The React-Native SDK actually handles initialization of your RCTEventEmitters.

As Arthur points out, using `NSNotificationCenter` to communicate with your `RCTEventEmitter` is a good strategy. You can also create a custom singleton class and register RCTEventEmitter's with it on initialization if you need pointers to these event emitters.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer I found for this issue, with a clear explanation of the causes.
An implementation can be found here: https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/1ebba84a0fd7c2e8b481e4f8a5349b99

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have a quick fix, not a very good idea but achieved what I want.

The problem is I can't get THE instance of `MyEventEmitter`, so I instead use notification center in native code to notify THE instance.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"NATIVE_WEIXIN_LOGIN_RESP_CODE"
                                                  object:nil
                                                  queue:nil
                                             usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull notification) {
                                               SendAuthResp *resp = notification.object;
                                                 [self sendEventWithName:@"WEIXIN_LOGIN_RESP_CODE" body:resp.code];
                                               }];
```

Can you still post what the correct way in React Native to do what I want?